# Proving $P[a\lt X \lt b]=F_X(b)-P[X=b]-F_X(a) $.

Tags: probability, random-variables

X is a random variable then :$$ \{X\lt b\}= \{X\lt a\} \cup\{a<X<b\}$$
and $$\{X\lt a\} \cap\{a<X<b\}=\phi.
$$ Hence
 $F_X(b)=P[a\lt X\lt b]+F_X(a) $.
Can anyone tell where I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one thing, your first equation is incorrect. You have excluded the case $X=a$ on the right side, but it is included on the left side.

When there are point masses involved, you have to be very careful in distinguishing "$X<k$" and "$X\leq k$".

Remember, too, that $F_X(k)=P[X\leq k]$.

So you should have

$$F_X(b)=P[X\leq b] = \overbrace{\underbrace{P[X\leq a]}_{F_X(a)} + P[a<X<b]}^{X<b} + \overbrace{P[X=b]}^{X=b}$$

which you can rearrange to get the desired result

$$\boxed{P[a<X<b] = F_X(b)-P[X=b]-F_X(a)}$$

Comment: then my first equation now become this $\{X\le b\}= \{X\le a\} \cup\{a<X<b\} \cup \{X=b\}$  and can you please explain why $F_X(k)=P[X\leq k]$ why $k$ is included ,i know that it is defined this way but there may be some logic behind that @ MPW